# Debug an app runnin of AVD

Tags: cordova, android-virtual-device

I added the `file-transfer` `cordova plugin` to my app to upload images, to test it i had to use the `AVD` since i can't do this on my browser.

the App run correctly on the `AVD` the `UI` showing but non of the function that needs to make HTTP calls on my server works, like login, Register or Upload an image. i made sure my server is up and running and things working so well on browser.

My question is how to `debug` my up while it's Running on `AVD`

Answer (score 0):

Bring up a command prompt (Windows)/terminal (Mac) window and run `adb logcat` to view the logcat output of the AVD in real-time.

If you want to write this to a file, do something like `adb logcat > debug.log`

If the AVD is Android 4.4+, you can connect Chrome developer tools to it - navigate to `chrome://inspect/#devices` in Chrome. You can view the network activity of the AVD Webview this way.